# PySpark sqlContext.read.load ArrayIndexOutofBounds Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a CSV file in S3 which has 420 rows and 54000 columns. I am trying to load the CSV into a Spark DataFrame:

```py
genoExp = sqlContext.read.load("/mnt/%s/RNA-Seq/GSE10846_Gene_Expression_Data.csv" %MOUNT_NAME, format='com.databricks.spark.csv', header='true', inferSchema = 'true')
```

This returns an error:

> com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 20480

There is no issue with smaller CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

20480 is a default limit of the number of columns but it can be increased using `maxColumns` option:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tempfile

np.random.seed(1)

(pd
    .DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (1, 30000)))
    .to_csv(path, header=True, index=False))

df = spark.read.option("maxColumns", "54000").csv(path, header=True)

df.columns[:4]
```

```
['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

```py
df.select(df.columns[:4]).show()
```

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
| 37| 12| 72|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

In practice it doesn't make much sense to use Spark (especially Spark SQL with sources which don't support projection push-down) for short and wide data like this. You could do a bit better with lower level API though.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by changing encode from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1